# How to change slides in slick slider without animation ? I

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I need to set slide in slick slider in input without animation effect.

Comment: 1.) What have you tried? 2.) As a UI/UX note removing animations like that are confusing to the user  3.) Can you not just set the speed to 0 in the options?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and especially read Why is [“Can someone help me?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) not an actual question?

Comment: Good for you. Please read the help pages.

Comment: I am sorry.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the documentation for slickGoTo. The second argument is a boolean that controls whether to animate or not. So:

```
var slide_number = 2;
$('.your-element').slick('slickGoTo', slide_number, false);
```

Comment: small correction. Last argument means "dont animate". So in this case we need to pass "true"